# EzPublish AcitivityTimeOut Setting

Tags: content-management-system, ezpublish

Good Day Guys,

I'm wondering if it's possible to set the ActivityTimeOut Setting for 30 days?

I actually tried putting it on 30 days... 2592000 secs = 30days..

however after several hours of inactivity EzPublish logout my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the eZ Publish documentation :

```
# Number of seconds before a session is considered inactive/logged out, 1 hour is standard
ActivityTimeout=3600
```

Looking at the kernel code, where this setting is used, it looks like that it does not have any effect on really disconnecting a user, it's just about **considering** a user as inactive (via the `fetchLoggedInList` function for instance) which is used in the Admin > Sessions section of the admin interface (if you're using sql stored session, which is not the default behavior in the last 4.x versions of eZ Publish).

Have you tried and checked these parameters ?

```
[Session]
# "Remember me" feature of the login.
# Number of seconds a session cookie will last,
# if an user wants to store current session to the cookie
# should click on "Remember me" checkbox on login page.
# Empty or 0 means this ability will be disabled and CookieTimeout will be used.
RememberMeTimeout=
# Number of seconds a session will last, 3 days is standard
SessionTimeout=259200
# Number of seconds a session cookie will last,
# 0 means until browser is closed
# Leaving the field empty means to use the default PHP settings (session.cookie_lifetime)
CookieTimeout=
```

As you can see, cookies are by default controller by your PHP server configuration, so you should have a look here too.